# "Getting build failure issue running through jenkins ci"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Below error is being encountered when creating a new build using jenkins ci

```
+ cd hybris/bin/platform
/home/jenkins-slave/workspace/23Feb-CI@tmp/durable-a94d2ffb/script.sh: line 2: cd: hybris/bin/platform: No such file or directory
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxjlZ.png

Comment: probably worth doing an `ls` and `pwd` to check you are in the correct location before the `cd` happens.

Comment: If you just open up a shell and try to change directory from the same path that your script is running from, are you able to get to it? Presumably you're just trying to get there from the wrong path

Comment: this path cd: hybris/bin/platform is missing also workspace directory path is different

Comment: can u suggest the steps to restore the path, here platform path is missing

Comment: seems this folder creates itself, checked workspace for its hybris application repository